# Are there any performance difference between Microsoft SQL server 2008 Editions

Tags: sql-server, performance, diff, windows

I always wonders this. For example you are using Microsoft SQL server 2008 web edition. It supports your hardware fully. And you upgraded it to Datacenter edition. would there be any performance difference at select,update,insert and delete queries between these 2 editions on same hardware ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you do. There are some feature differnces (like page / row level compression), which can result in different performacne when used. THen there is the issue in maintenance - online index rebuild (without dropping FIRST).

Comment: can you explain detailed. i really want to hear thank you. or you can give me a link which explains well.

Comment: a link? http://www.microsoft.com/SqlServer. Go to the differences between editions.

Comment: TomTom that does not explain me anything. Those edition differences. instead of features i wonder performance criteria.

Comment: Well, then seriously get the experience yourself. If you are not willing to read the sections of the site- I am not willing to help you.